Тестовая задачка с собеседования на C# — реализовать метод как можно универсальнее
Задачка с собеса С#, уровень middle/senior (ИМХО) на подумать и покодить классы.
Я изменил формулировку, но суть не меняется. Также предоставлю ниже своё решение.

Существует три метода, которые меняют информацию о товаре:

Изменяющий состояние;
Изменяющий состов тегов;
Задающий вес.

Так как в дальнейшем планируется добавить еще 10-20 методов, которые меняют информацю о товаре (сами методы могут быть реализованы как nuget в другом сервисе), нужно реализовать единственный метод DoSomethingWithItem, который в зависимости от входных параметров мог бы вызывать любое изменение товара.
То есть методу может быть сказано "Поменяй состояние" или "Задай вес" и так далее, и его реализация уже сама вызовет один из методов StateChanger.Change или WeightSetter.Set и т. д.
Классы StateChanger, TagsSetter и WeightSetter можно менять. Главное сохранить бизнес-функциональность.

Образец кода:
namespace ProductsService
{
    public sealed class StateChanger
    {
        public enum State
        {
            Active,
            InActive
        }

        private void Change(int itemId, State newState)
        {
        }
    }

    public sealed class TagsSetter
    {
        public void Set(int itemId, string[] tags)
        {
        }
    }

    public sealed class WeightSetter
    {
        public void Set(int itemId, int weight)
        {
        }
    }

    public sealed class ProductsService
    {
        public void DoSomeActionWithProdcut()
        {
        }
    }
}

Вопросы следующие:

Хорошо ли мое решение (c учётом того что "собес")?
Может можно по-другому, по-лучше?

Накидывайте своё решение — хочется увидеть и другие варианты.

Что по поводу транзакционности? Например, есть ли вариант где надо сделать 2 изменения? Условно, поменять вес и теги, должна ли это быть 1 транзакция?

уровень middle\senior (ИМХО) не, мне кажется это уровня джуна примерно , всего лишь порефачить немного код. Хотя много не ясно в задании, например, какие именно проблемы в изначальном варианте предлагается решить? Какие требования для отрефаченного кода?

Про транзакционность прямо не сказано. Врятли она ожидается от решения - но вопрос неплохой.

Вопрос про транзакционость сам по себе следует из вопроса "какие изменения можно сделать с объектом, надо ли огриничивать эти изменения определенным набором и можно ли их комбинировать?" - это второе что я бы спросил на собесе.

хотя тут в принципе не ясно, в чем бизнес нужда менять именно конкретно только состояние, теги и вес? Да и зачем для этого выдумывать аж 3 класса? Это же просто усложнение на ровном месте. Нельзя сделать один метод update(Product product) в одном классе и просто его использовать?

В моем понимании здесь упор надо сделать на универсальность метода - добавляются новые сеттеры, вызывающий метод (API) должен быть неизменным. Возможно здесь DI ещё от собеседующего применить ожидается...но это не точно.

потому надо сразу уточнять, какую проблему надо решить? Плоджить классы ради изменения одного поля - за такое надо бить по рукам, потому это может быть просто надуменный пример для демонстрации знаний ООП, если так - то можно конечно написать сложный расширяемый код для этого. Но в реальном проекте я бы такому не обрадовался.

Плюс добивать какие то новые операции в отдельном nuget пакете? Это вообще что и зачем так? Чуствую себя старым ворчуном, просто пример кмк далек от реальной задачи )

любое изменение товара - какое еще изменение кроме веса, тегов и состояния может быть?

"Плюс добивать какие то новые операции в отдельном nuget пакете? Это вообще что и зачем так?" - наверное имеется ввиду одни люди добавляют функциональность и распространяют через нюгет. Такой подход распространен при микросервисах или еще где..вобщем там где много команд всяких.
"любое изменение товара" - например цена, объем, партия. Каждый класс (сервис) свое и меняет.

не, обычно в микросеврисах могут выкатить библиотеку для доступа к API, но очень сомневаюсь что там будут писать какую то сложную логику типа как здесь )

Давайте сначала про то, что вам сказано в задании:

нужно реализовать единственный метод DoSomethingWithItem который в зависимости от входных параметров мог бы вызывать любое изменение товара.

То есть реализация этого метода есть критерий законченности ответа.
Далее, в качестве принципов решения:

Мы должны ограничить набор изменений на нашей стороне, мы позволяем клиенту менять только то, что разрешено нами.
Код должен позволять будущие изменения чего угодно. Мы должны иметь возможность расширить набор потенциальных изменений в продукте.
Введение нового типа изменения в продукте не должно отразиться на сущесутвующем коде клиентов
Делать изменение транзакционным или нет - это будет деталь реализации DoSomeActionWithProdcut, которую мы можем поменять в любой момент.
Мы ставим в приоритет композицию наследованию как основной постулат изменений

Далее, нам нужен объект, котрый предсатвляет собой изменение продукта. Требования к объекту:

ИД продукта должен быть обязательно предоставлен
Должен поддерживать несколько изменений сразу
Легко добавить новые типы изменений в будущем

public sealed class ProductUpdate
{
    public int ProductId { get; private set; }
    public int? Weight { get; private set; }
    public string[] Tags { get; private set; }
    public StateChanger.State? state { get; private set; }

    private ProductUpdate(int productId)
    {
        this.ProductId = productId;
    }

    public static ProductUpdate NewUpdate(int productId)
    {
        return new ProductUpdate(productId);
    }

    public ProductUpdate WithWeight(int weight)
    {
        this.Weight = weight;
        return this;
    }

    public ProductUpdate WithTags(string[] tags)
    {
        this.Tags = tags;
        return this;
    }

    public ProductUpdate WithState(StateChanger.State state)
    {
        this.state = state;
        return this;
    }
}

Класс выше предсталяет собой что то типа Билдера для изменения продукта. Все возможные изменения контролируются отдельными статическими методами. Почему не просто свойствами? Можно и просто свойствами, но мы потенциально можем иметь сложную логику создания подобного объекта (например, что если какие то поля меняются только в паре?), потому использовать Builder для подобного кажется разумным.
После этого, ProductService выглядит тривиально
public sealed class ProductsService
{
    public void DoSomeActionWithProdcut(ProductUpdate update)
    {
        if (update.Weight.HasValue) new WeightSetter().Set(update.ProductId, update.Weight.Value);
        if (update.Tags != null) new TagsSetter().Set(update.ProductId, update.Tags);
        if (update.state.HasValue) new StateChanger().Change(update.ProductId, update.state.Value);
    }
}

Если нужна транзакционность, можно добавить это в DoSomeActionWithProdcut. Поддержка нового типа изменения будет простой - добавлением поля в ProductUpdate и нового класса xxxChanger.
Пример использования
var productUpdate = ProductUpdate.NewUpdate(1)
    .WithState(UserQuery.StateChanger.State.Active)
    .WithWeight(10);
    
var productService = new ProductsService();
productService.DoSomeActionWithProdcut(productUpdate);  

Преимущества решения:

Клиенту нет шанса ошибиться, ему надо только подготовить нужные изменения в ProductUpdate и отправить его в ProductService, всё.
Мы контролируем и типы изменений и как они выполняются
Добавление нового типа изменений не ломает существующих клиентов
Никаких сложностей с наследованиями для клиентов
Способ, как выполняется изменение, скрыт от клиента - это просто деталь реализации нашего ProductService


Так как в дальнейшем планируется добавить еще 10-20 методов, которые меняют информацю о товаре (сами методы могут быть реализованы как nuget в другом сервисе)

Другие методы в другом сервисе могут использовать ProductUpdate для подготовки любой комбинации разрешенных на продукте изменений. Добавление новых типов изменений должно быть контролируемо только нами как владельцами модели продукта.
Пример
public ProductUpdate ImMethodFromOtherNuGetPackage(ProductUpdate update)
{
    return update
        .WithState(UserQuery.StateChanger.State.Active)
        .WithWeight(100);
}

Кажется, всё из задания учел. Для пуристов, можно сделать прямо отдельный ProductUpdateBuilder следуя всем канонам ООП - пусть будет как домашнее задание.

"Поддержка нового типа изменения будет простой - добавлением поля в ProductUpdate и нового класса xxxChanger" - ну и еще добавить новую ветку в метод DoSomeActionWithProduct. Не много ли? Мне кажется, что в задании наоборот хотели чтобы при добавлении нового поля этот метод не требовалось бы дописывать. За реализацию спасибо Вам.

что то где то придется дописывать. К тому же, в задании сказано явно То есть методу может быть сказано "Поменяй состояние" или "Задай вес" и так далее, и его реализация уже сама вызовет один из методов StateChanger.Change или WeightSetter.Set и т. д. по сути прямым текстом говорят, как реализовать метод.

Не много ли? - для клиента не много, для нас только необходимая работа, ничего лишнего.

Предлогаю использовать лямбды.
Дано:
public class Product
{
    public int Weight { get; set; }
    public State State { get; set; }
    public string[] Tags { get; set; }
}
public enum State
{
    Active,
    InActive
}

Сервис с одним методом:
public class ProductService
{
    public void DoSomething(Product product, Action<Product> action)
    {
        action(product);
    }
}

Используем:
var product = new Product { Weight = 10, State = State.InActive, Tags = [] };
Console.WriteLine($"{product.Weight} {product.State} {string.Join(',', product.Tags)}");

var service = new ProductService();

service.DoSomething(product, p => p.Weight += 20);
service.DoSomething(product, p => p.State = State.Active);
service.DoSomething(product, p => p.Tags = ["Foo", "Bar"]);

Console.WriteLine($"{product.Weight} {product.State} {string.Join(',', product.Tags)}");

Конечно, получилось масло масляное, т. к. можно выкинуть этот сервис и писать просто:
product.Weight += 20;
product.State = State.Active;
product.Tags = ["Foo", "Bar"];

Но если действие встроено в пайплайн обработки, то это имеет смысл:
public void DoSomething(Action<Product> action)
{
    var product = productRepository.Get();
    action(product);
    productRepository.Save(product);
}


То есть методу может быть сказано "Поменяй состояние" или "Задай вес" и так далее, и его реализация уже сама вызовет один из методов StateChanger.Change или WeightSetter.Set - то есть есть заранее набор классов для каждого изменения, а значит список того, что можно поменять в продукте, ограничен, но не бъётся с Action<Product> action который по сути поволяет менять всё. Условно, если у продукта есть поле цена, которое мы не хотим позволять менять нашим клиентам, клиенты об этом узнают только опытным путем =)

@tym32167 - Думаю, тут можно прикрутить обёртку. Метод принимает не Product, а ProductWrapper, у которого выставлены только те свойства, которые можно менять.

Да, тогда придёте плюс минус к тому же решению, что у меня ))

namespace ProductsService
{  
    public interface ISetter<T>
    {
        void Set(int itemId, T data);
    }

    public sealed class StateChanger : ISetter<StateChanger.State>
    {
        public enum State
        {
            Active,
            InActive
        }

        public void Set(int itemId, State newState) => Change(itemId, newState);

        private static void Change(int itemId, State newState)
            => Console.WriteLine($"Call StateChanger.Set(itemId = {itemId}, newState = {newState})");
    }

    public sealed class TagsSetter : ISetter<string[]> 
    {
        public void Set(int itemId, string[] tags)
            => Console.WriteLine($"Call TagsSetter.Set(itemId = {itemId}, tags = {string.Join(",", tags)})");
    }

    public sealed class WeightSetter : ISetter<int>
    {
        public void Set(int itemId, int weight)
            => Console.WriteLine($"Call WeightSetter.Set(itemId = {itemId}, weight = {weight})");
    }

    public sealed class ProductsService
    {
        //Isetter - конкретный сеттер itemId - айди товара data - данные для изменения
        //Тут лучше шаблонизировать - это уберегаетот неправильного вызова типа: DoSomeActionWithProduct(new StateChanger, 1, "some")
        public void DoSomeActionWithProduct<T>(ISetter<T> setter, int itemId, T data)
            => setter.Set(itemId, data);        
    }
}


Какие плюсы этого подхода в сравнении с изначальным вариантом?

пару комментариев добавлю пожалуй. Первое - это решение навряд ли сгодится по той причине, что клиенту, создавая новый класс, придется реализовывать метод Change - а что он в нем писать будет? В это методе, по идее, должен быть запрос в БД там или куда надо, так? Если клиент может и так отправить запрос в БД, то зачем ему пояски с классами?

вторая причнина почему ответ не прокатит - интерфейс ISetter позволяем писать вообще что угодно внутри. Например, попытаться обновить поле, которого нет в продукте.

Начинаем "код ревью".

Наверное имели ввиду Set? Change как раз нужно сделать private - привести все к одному интерфейсу. Это точно правильно с точки зрения что ожидалось. Дальше не понимаю)



ISetter - согласен. Его нужно удалить. Поправлю

